# Send over 200000 characters using send_keys in selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create an HTML table from excel sheet and copy it to a webpage. I am using Send_Keys to send over 200000 characters (indifferent lines) to a webpage but it is causing memory issue and crashing jupyter. My code is as below. I am looking for ways/alternatives to speed up the process to copy the variable x in my code on the webpage.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel(r'.xlsx', sheet_name='')

x = sheet_to_df_map.to_html()
x = str(x)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "editPageLink"))).click()

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"wysiwygTextarea_ifr")))

button1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body[@data-id='wysiwygTextarea']//p")))

button1.click()
button1.send_keys(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this problem before, I broke my string up into batches. You can split by something like newline, but if you don't know how long each line will be, you can simply split by specific lengths (number of characters), but if you have a lot of unicode and stuff, this may not be the best approach either. Judge what works best for you.

```
interval = 1000 # No of characters
lines = [x[i:i+interval] for i in range(0, len(x), interval)]

for l in lines:
    button1.send_keys(l)
```

Personal Comment: This is not a time efficient approach however because it significantly increases time taken to type in everything. I ended up using multi-threading to make this work while I did other things. I'm sure others may be able to come up with better solutions, but this is what I settled for.